# How to use regex to decode a message header back to its originating object?

Tags: c#, regex

C# Regex
I am trying to learn more about regex.

Lets say I have a class defined as:

```
public class MyClass
 {
     Point      TopLeft;
     FontStyle  fontStyle;
     FontWeight fontWeight;
     String     Message;  
 }
```

Which I then serialize as:

```
 string s = string.Format("\u0001 ({0},{1}), {2}, {3} \u0003 {4}",
             TopLeft.X, TopLeft.Y, fontStyle, fontWeight, Message);
```

Many such strings s will then be added together and sent to the backend database (PostgreSQL 9.6).

Later, I recall all such strings from the database. Regex is then used to split the strings back to their original items:

```
        string pattern = @"\u0001";
        string input = pndt.transcription;
        string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Can regex now be used to further parse the serialized string back to its original object of MyClass?  That is, how can regex be used to "decode" the formated string created with the above string.format back to its original object?

Any help is much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Is there any reason for this serialization format instead of JSON or XML?

Comment: @SirRufo  Nope. Just playing and trying to learn somthing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a new object: `var obj = new MyClass()` and assign the values from the string. **This is not possible with regex alone**, but you can try to parse the string for the properties you need to assign.

You haven't posted examples, so I assume an example entry of `result` looks like this: `(14,27), italic, 33 \u0003 This is a message :)`

A pattern to parse this would be `^\((\d+),(\d+)\), (\w+), (\d+) \u0003 (.*)$`

Then fetch the groups and create your object.

Comment: Can this pattern matching be expanded to use Capture Groups?

Comment: It already is (but I fixed a typo right now). Capture groups are defined by parentheses. Do you mean named capture groups?

Comment: yes. BTW, I removed the spaces from my string.fromat and added float capture (as a Point), with  Regex r = new Regex(@"\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\),(\w+),(\w+)\u0003(.*)");  which works. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it can, and it's very easy. [You can read the syntax here](http://regular-expressions.mobi/named.html?wlr=1)

Answer (score 0):

As @Pharaoh suggested, here is a complete working test of what I had in mind:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void RegexSerialization()
    {

        MedicalServiceClient client = new MedicalServiceClient();

        // Save a test value
        int patient_recid = 15478;
        DateTime tservice = new DateTime(2017, 4, 28);
        byte[] _transcriptStrokes = null;
        string _transcript = null;

        MyClass test_1 = new MyClass
        {
            TopLeft = new Point(24.11, 36.22),
            fontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
            fontStyle = FontStyles.Italic,
            Message = "This is my first test string."
        };

        MyClass test_2 = new MyClass
        {
            TopLeft = new Point(14.15, 24.22),
            fontWeight = FontWeights.Light,
            fontStyle = FontStyles.Oblique,
            Message = "This is my second test string."
        };

        MyClass test_3 = new MyClass
        {
            TopLeft = new Point(7, 12),
            fontWeight = FontWeights.Thin,
            fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal,
            Message = "This is my third test string."
        };

        List<MyClass> _mylist = new List<MyClass>();
        _mylist.Add(test_1);
        _mylist.Add(test_2);
        _mylist.Add(test_3);

        _transcript = string.Empty;

        foreach(var s in _mylist)
        {
            // serialize 
            string _s = string.Format("\u0001({0},{1}),{2},{3}\u0003{4}",
                     s.TopLeft.X, s.TopLeft.Y, s.fontStyle, s.fontWeight, s.Message);
            _transcript = _transcript + _s;
        }

        // Save to backend database.
        client.SaveDrawingTranscipt(patient_recid, tservice, _transcriptStrokes, _transcript);

        // Recall from backend database.
        List<MyClass> _newlist = new List<MyClass>();

        progress_note_drawing_transcription pndt = client.GetDrawingTranscript(patient_recid, tservice);

        // regex pattern for integer or double. The (?:  starts a non-capturing group. The ? after ) makes the .d+ purely optional.
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\),(\w+),(\w+)\u0003(.*)");

        // Parse the transcription field into multiple strings using the non-printable character \x01
        string pattern = @"\u0001";
        string input = pndt.transcription;
        string[] result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < result.Length; ctr++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result[ctr]))
                 continue;

            Match m = r.Match(result[ctr]);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                MyClass _mc = new MyClass();
                Point _p = new Point();
                _p.X = double.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
                _p.Y = double.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value);
                _mc.TopLeft = _p;
                _mc.fontStyle = (FontStyle)new FontStyleConverter().ConvertFromString(m.Groups[3].Value);
                _mc.fontWeight = (FontWeight)new FontWeightConverter().ConvertFromString(m.Groups[4].Value);
                _mc.Message = m.Groups[5].Value;

                _newlist.Add(_mc);
            }
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[0].TopLeft, _newlist[0].TopLeft);
        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[1].TopLeft, _newlist[1].TopLeft);
        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[2].TopLeft, _newlist[2].TopLeft);

        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[0].fontStyle, _newlist[0].fontStyle);
        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[1].fontStyle, _newlist[1].fontStyle);
        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[2].fontStyle, _newlist[2].fontStyle);

        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[0].fontWeight, _newlist[0].fontWeight);
        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[1].fontWeight, _newlist[1].fontWeight);
        Assert.AreEqual(_mylist[2].fontWeight, _newlist[2].fontWeight);



    }
```

It took awhile to work with the structures of FontStyles and FontWeights in System.Windows.

Hope it helps somebody. :)